# Python: Altering value of a mismatched key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

This code needs to find the most frequent *k-mers* (substrings of k letters) with *d* mismatches in a string (genome). In the past I had to find the most frequent *k-mer* without mismatches and I'm trying minimally alter my code. To do so, I would have to be able to increment values in a dictionary that have a different key from a string I'm passing. Is that possible? Below is my code. Is there a way to do what I have written in the comment? `HammingDistance()` just computes the number of differences between 2 strings.

```
import operator

def MostFrequentKmer (Text, k, d):
    kmerDict = {}
    freqKmers = list()

    for i in range (0, len(Text)-k+1):
        kmer = Text[i:i+k]
        if kmer in kmerDict:
            kmerDict[kmer] += 1

        #elif a key exists for which HammingDistance(key, kmer) <= d, then increment the value associated with that key

        else:
            kmerDict[kmer] = 1

    maxVal = max(zip(kmerDict.values()))[0]

    for k, v in kmerDict.items():
        if v == maxVal:
            freqKmers.append(k)

    print(sorted(freqKmers))


def HammingDistance (str1, str2):
    hamDis = 0
    for i in range(0, len(str1)):
        if str1[i] != str2[i]:
            hamDis += 1
    return hamDis
```

Example IO is:
Input- ("ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT", 4, 1)
Output- ["ATGC", "ATGT", "GATG"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to 1) increment the count for all closest keys and 2) add an entry if there are no closest keys, the below does what you want.

```
else:
  close_keys = [k for k in kmerDict.keys() if HammingDistance(k, kmer) <= d]
  if close_keys:
    for k in close_keys:
      kmerDict[k] += 1
  else:
    kmerDict[k] = 1
```

As an aside, please consider following python naming conventions, e.g., change `HammingDistance` to `hamming_distance`.

Comment: I like your solution. I could see an implementation involving the `collections.Counter` class for the `kmerDict` but it could be overkill. [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).